# Can a client send a message to more than one server concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I know that we can use multithreading to ensure that a server can accept connections from many clients. This code helps many clients connect to a server.

```
s = new ServerSocket(1500);

while(true)
{
    Socket socket = s.accept();
    new ClientThread1(socket).start();
}
```

But, can a client connect to more than one server the same way? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Basically you need to reverse the idea and have multiple threads on the client, each managing a connection to a different server or port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fork a new Thread() for each server you want to connect to, and have each Thread connect to a different server.

As far as each Thread is concerned, it will only be connecting to one server as normal. You just need to use some global variables or something to make sure each Thread knows what server it is suppose to be connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I can do so because connection is a tuple of client(ip:port) and server(ip:port). If done concurrently and each tuple remains unique, it should be possible